# Combining JSON tables from server in Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, server

I am a beginner coder and I am learning Android from Ravi's [tutorials](http://www.androidhive.info/). Currently, I am trying to combine two tutorials - [login/register](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and [listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) (*I put the two links here so I don't have to post a bunch of code*).

I am making an app where user registers and he is able to add a movie. The added movie is saved on the server. I made an activity similar to the register activity and it enables user to add a movie with the following info:

```
JSONObject movie= jObj.getJSONObject("movie");
String id = movie.getString("id"); 
String userId = movie.getString("user_id");  // this is the current user's id
String title = movie.getString("title");
String genre = movie.getString("genre");
String year = movie.getString("year");
```

And my php class for adding a movie:

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['genre']) && isset($_POST['year'])) {

// receiving the post params
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

// create a new movie
$movie = $db->storeMovie($user_id, $title, $genre, $year);
if ($movie) {
    // movie stored successfully
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["movie"]["id"] = $movie["id"];
    $response["movie"]["user_id"] = $movie["user_id"];
    $response["movie"]["title"] = $movie["title"];
    $response["movie"]["genre"] = $movie["genre"];
    $response["movie"]["year"] = $movie["year"];
    $response["movie"]["created_datetime"] = $movie["created_datetime"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // movie failed to store
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in movie creation!";
     echo json_encode($response);
}

} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Some of the required parameters are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Now I want to ***return the added movie***, but I also want to ***return the name of the user who added the movie*** instead of the user_id. What is the best way to do this if I only have the user_id from the stored_user table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run another query on `stored_user` table for getting user's info related to `user_id` and assign that object to the `user` object in  your response. It will automatically get encoded into `json` as follows

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "title": "xyz",
  "genre": "abc",
  "year": "2006",
  "user": {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "User's name",
    "email": "User's email"
  }
}
```

Comment: What should that query look alike to get the info from a tutorial like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)?

Comment: @Kemo you can write function like this  `public function getUserById($id) {
 
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
 
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
 
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

                return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }`

Comment: One more question - this code should make this `// Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;`
work in my MoviesActivity? 

No need to add `http://api.androidhive.info/json/stored_user.json`?

Comment: @Kemo for fetching Movie list you need to fetch `http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json` And for fetching user info you need to fetch `http://api.androidhive.info/json/stored_user.json` url